Resolving "Invalid argument (22)" error in Rsync when syncing large datasets
I am using rsync to sync around ~2TB of data.
I get the following errors in the log file:
rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/mnt/sd25-4tb-bkp4-mnt4/tns-maindatads-smb/tns-maindatads-smb/main-data-subds-1/GoogleDrive-alk8915-bkp-2024-07-09-1800/Programirane neshta failove alk19890105/SoftUni/SoftUni AI 2021 Materials/SoftUni - AI - Data Science June 2021/softuni-ai-datascience-2021-project-FINAL-SUBMISSION/softuni-ai-datascience-2021-project-atkuzmanov-FINAL/resources/images/.Icon\#015.pu2lTm" failed: Invalid argument (22)

I researched around for this error, but everywhere I found related to ownership, which should not be my case, as I am using --no-o and --no-g.
I think it is probably related to some special symbols, such as new line or ":" (colon).
I definitely have some files and directories which contain ":" (colon), they are system files and I want to be able to synchronize them without renaming them as this will cause problems. How can I do that?
Here is the rsync sync command I am running with the flags:
rsync -avvvzh \
  "$SRC" \
  "$DEST_DIR" \
  --log-file=$log_file \
  --progress \
  --links \
  --checksum \
  --bwlimit="192M" \
  --delete-during \
  --delete \
  --timeout="60" \
  --compress \
  --no-o \
  --no-g

Rsync version:
rsync --version
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2022 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: https://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, symlinks, symtimes, hardlinks, hardlink-specials,
    hardlink-symlinks, IPv6, atimes, batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs,
    xattrs, optional secluded-args, iconv, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    SIMD-roll, no asm-roll, openssl-crypto, no asm-MD5
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 sha1 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
Daemon auth list:
    sha512 sha256 sha1 md5 md4

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.

Ubuntu Server version:
ubuntu 24.04 (64 bit) LTS


rsync handles pretty much all possible file names without problem. What is the file system on your target device?

what happens if you don't use any of the many many command line options here, but simply rsync ${SRC} ${DST} (and only use --no-o and --no-g if you really need them)

It looks like the EINVAL is coming from the mkstemp (3) library call, and supposedly means "The last six characters of template were not XXXXXX". I wonder if the long pathname is causing the template to get truncated somehow?

No point using --checksum, --bwlimit, --compress or -z, and if you're saying no owner & no group just replace -a with -rt. And if it's a single file you don't need -r

What are the source and destination filesystems? Not all filesystems can handle colons

@MarcusMüller, thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it!
Here is an example of a file name: 2024-08-14T08:34:36Z
The file system on the target device is ExFAT.
I thought that should handle colons or am I mistaking?

@steeldriver, thank you very much for your reply! I don't know, is there any way I can find out if it's too long, what's the limit?

@ChrisDavies, thank you for your help! The source system is a locally mounted  TrueNas Scale SMB share.
And the destination file system is a local ExFAT SSD attached via SATA via a SAS Controller.

", but simply rsync ${SRC} ${DST} " @MarcusMüller, that's how I started with, and that's how the problem started.

@atkuzmanov and, have adding these many options really made you any smarter on where the actual problem is? Have you gotten any statistically relevant amount of faster? You also are adding in options that are designed to make operations less safe, or slower. It's really just you trying out options that you don't understand, and this kind of trial and error will not lead anywhere.

Great. Please add the extra information you've provided here in the comments into your question. If you put all the detail in the one place it's much easier for people to read it and help you

@atkuzmanov I dug into the source a bit more, and it looks likely that the error is misreported as being from mkstemp. The rsync code wraps the call in its own do_mkstemp that both generates the temporary filename and opens the file with requested permissions, but the calling context reports failure of do_mkstemp as a failure of mkstemp regardless. It is more likely from the file creation I think (if mkstemp itself had failed, the file name would be returned with template suffix .XXXXXX instead of the temporary file suffix .pu2lTm).


I definitely have some files and directories which contain ":" (colon), they are system files and I want to be able to synchronize them without renaming them as this will cause problems. How can I do that?

You need to either put them on a filesystem where such symbols are supported in filenames, you need to containerize them (like a tar or zip file), or you need to change the filename to only using supported characters.   None of this is an rsync specific issue as it is simply trying to keep the same name in both places.   If the name is not compatible with the destination, it's going to have problems.
Since your destination is under /mnt, it seems more likely that you might have something like a FAT* or NTFS volume there that does not allow backslashes in a filename.  Check what fileystem you have mounted there and what characters are not valid for files in that filesystem.

From comments, this filesystem is ExFAT.   From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification#table-35-invalid-filename-characters, both the colon (mentioned in the question) and backslash (seen in the error message) are invalid as filename characters.

thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it! Here is an example of a file name: 2024-08-14T08:34:36Z The source system is a locally mounted TrueNas Scale SMB share. And the destination file system is a local ExFAT SSD attached via SATA via a SAS Controller. I thought that ExFat should handle colons or am I mistaking?

@atkuzmanov nothing here indicates a colon is a problem; but the length of the paths or the presence of special characters might be. ExFAT is simply not a sensible file system for your use case of backing up. Use something else.

@MarcusMüller, TrueNas Scale uses ZFS file system, so I wanted to back up some data from it to a more compatible file system. I thought ExFat was the most widely compatible one in terms of being able to attach it to loads of different OSs, MacOS, Ubuntu, Windows, etc. Which file system would you suggest in this case?

honestly, all the standard file systems on Linux, ext4, XFS, … will all serve you well here. Windows can these days, through WSL, mount all of them.

@MarcusMüller, that makes sense, I will do some research on which to choose, ext4, XFS, or somethig... and I will give it a try as soon as I get some time to migrate, and I will report back how it went. Thank you for your help!

@atkuzmanov research, but don't overdo it. This is an external device attached via USB. The file system won't be the speed-limiting factor if you choose any of the standard file systems. Try this: df -T ~. That's shows the file system your current setup uses as file system for your files. That one is fine. Use it.

I will give it a try. It's actually attached via a SAS controller via SATA to a hot-swap HDD/SSD drawer caddy.

then go for XFS or ext4, seriously, this should really not be used with exFAT.

@MarcusMüller, update with more info, from the command you suggested:
df -T /mnt/sd25-4tb-bkp4-mnt4

Filesystem     Type   1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       exfat 3906897664 3780869120 126028544  97% /mnt/sd25-4tb-bkp4-mnt4


df -T /mnt/tns-temp-smb

Filesystem                     Type  1K-blocks  Used  Available Use% Mounted on
//192.168.X.X/temp-smb cifs 3731616000   128 3731615872   1% /mnt/tns-temp-smb


@atkuzmanov, please add the extra information you've provided here in the comments into your question. If you put all the detail in the one place it's much easier for people to read it and help you

@atkuzmanov, added a reference for the list of invalid characters in ExFAT.
